# Using 1 loop instead of 6 in Java

Tags: java, api, rest-assured

```
@When("User fetches the sms template from the templates fetched")
public void user_fetches_the_sms_template_from_the_templates_fetched() {
    List<String> jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("agent_sms_missed_call")) {
            agentMissedCallId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("caller_sms_missed_call")) {
            callerMissedCallSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("agent_sms_received_call")) {
            agentReceivedCallSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("caller_sms_received_call")) {
            callerReceivedCallSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("answered_on_ivr_sms")) {
            answeredOnIvrSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals("answered_on_auto_attendant_sms")) 
   {
            answeredOnAaSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
            break;
        }
    }
    }
```

Instead of using 6 loops i want to achieve in 1 loop and 6 flag variable so that it goes in IF condition only once. How can i achieve he same ?  I am using this rest assured api automation testing.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 kindly help

Comment: What are you trying to do? I mean your goal, not your code.

Comment: I think you have general problem with the assertions. Map the response to an object and then assert everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with JSON or REST-Assured. My response will reflect that. Also, my response will reflect what my nickname (user name) suggests.

The `for` loop statements are all the same: `for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++)`. Assuming nothing done inside the loop changes `jsonResponse`, you should be able to condense them into one:

```
@When("User fetches the sms template from the templates fetched")
public void user_fetches_the_sms_template_from_the_templates_fetched() {
List<String> jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");

for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
    if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals ("agent_sms_missed_call")) {
        agentMissedCallId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]"); 
    }

     if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals ("caller_sms_missed_call")) {
        callerMissedCallSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]"); 
     }
 
 // and 4 more similar if ( ...
```

This ignores the `break` statements in each `if` block of the original code. That might be acceptable. But, it would help to know why the `break` statements are there.

- For efficiency? Once all 6 matches are found, there is no need to continue the loop. This could be important if `jsonResponse.size()` is large. If small, it's not important.
- Is there the possibility of duplicates? If so, is it important to find only the first match?
- Other?

If "first match" is required, and `jsonResponse.size()` is small enough, the "first match" criterion could be preserved by running the `for` loop with decrement:

```
  for (int i = jsonResponse.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Another suggestion:

```
@When("User fetches the sms template from the templates fetched")
public void user_fetches_the_sms_template_from_the_templates_fetched() {
List<String> jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");

boolean agentMissSet, callerMissSet, agentReceiveSet, callerRecieveSet;
boolean answeredIvrSet, answeredAAset;

agentMissSet = callerMissSet = agentReceiveSet =  callerRecieveSet
    = answeredIvrSet = answeredAAset = false;

for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
    if (( ! agentMissSet) && 
          getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals  ("agent_sms_missed_call")) {
        agentMissedCallId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
        agentMissSet = true;
    }

     if (( ! callerMissedSet) &&
          getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals ("caller_sms_missed_call")) {
        callerMissedCallSmsId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
        callerMissSet = true;
      }
    
     // and four more similar if (...
```

This address the possibility of duplicates issue but not the efficiency issue, if `jsonResponse.size()` is  large. To fix the efficiency issue, add this just before the closing `}` of the `for` loop code block:

```
  if (     agentMissSet     && callerMissSet  && agentReceiveSet 
        && callerRecieveSet && answeredIvrSet && answeredAAset ) break;
```

I don't know what the values of `agentMissedCallId`, `callerMissedCallSmsId`, and the other 4 are before the `for` loop. If they are `null` or empty, or  have some other common default value, that could be used instead of the 6 `boolean`. This example assumes they will be `null`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size(); i++) {
    if ( agentMissedCallId != null && 
          getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals  ("agent_sms_missed_call")) {
        agentMissedCallId = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");

  // and 5 more similar ...
```

That assumes `getJsonPath` is not going to return `null`, empty, or whatever is used for the "already set test".

The replacement of the `if` statement testing 6 `boolean`, if used,  would be an `if` statement testing 6 `String` against `null`, empty, or other default value.

One problem I see with my suggested changes is that the code seems to have gotten uglier. And the 6 `if` statement and blocks have almost the same code. When I see occurrences of same code, one thing I think of is arrays. Here is how to use two `for` loops, and arrays:

```
 @When("User fetches the sms template from the templates fetched")
 public void user_fetches_the_sms_template_from_the_templates_fetched() {
 List<String> jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
 String [] id = {  agentMissedCallId      , callerMissedCallSmsId  , 
                   agentReceivedCallSmsId , callerReceivedCallSmsId , 
                   answeredOnIvrSmsId     , answeredOnAaSmsId                       
 };
 String [] type = {"agent_sms_missed_call"   , "caller_sms_missed_call",
                   "agent_sms_received_call" , "caller_sms_received_call",
                   "answered_on_ivr_sms"     , "answered_on_auto_attendant_sms"
                  };

 for (int j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size (); i++) {
        if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals(type[j])) {
             id [j] = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
             break;
        } 
      }
   }
 }
```

The above assumes `jsonResponse.size()` is small, and it's not  unreasonable iterate through it 6 times.

The following has the loops nested in the opposite order:

```
 @When("User fetches the sms template from the templates fetched")
 public void user_fetches_the_sms_template_from_the_templates_fetched() {
 List<String> jsonResponse = response.jsonPath().getList("$");
 String [] id = {  agentMissedCallId      , callerMissedCallSmsId  , 
                   agentReceivedCallSmsId , callerReceivedCallSmsId , 
                   answeredOnIvrSmsId     , answeredOnAaSmsId                       
 };
 String [] type = {"agent_sms_missed_call"   , "caller_sms_missed_call",
                   "agent_sms_received_call" , "caller_sms_received_call",
                   "answered_on_ivr_sms"     , "answered_on_auto_attendant_sms"
                  };
 boolean [] matchFound = new boolean [6];
 
  int matchCount = 0;
  Arrays.fill (matchFound, false);   
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.size () && matchCount < 6; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < id.length; j++) {
       if (matchFound[j]) { continue; }
       if (getJsonPath(response, "type[" + i + "]").equals(type[j])) {
             id [j] = getJsonPath(response, "id[" + i + "]");
          matchFound [j] = true;           
          matchCount++;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

## Notes:

- I assumed `getJsonPath` returns a `String`. If it returns some other type of `Object`, use that type for the `id` array.
- Having tightly coupled arrays suggests room for improvement. Consider having a helper class in which each instance has one `id`, one `type` and maybe one `matchFound`. That way, you can have one array.
- I responded to the question in the header: How to reduce the number of `for` loops. I suspect the code can be improved by making `jsonResponse` some other `Collection`, possibly a `Map`. But, in my judgement, that would be off-topic. Also, I lack sufficient information to be able to elaborate. Perhaps the O/P could followup with a new question. The new question could have some explanation of what the code is to accomplish, and reference this question.
- This answer lacks focus. This is the result of several "unknowns". Rather than asking the O/P several questions via the question comments, I attempted to cover several unknowns in a single answer. If the O/P provides more information, I can delete parts of this answer that would then become irrelevant, and otherwise improve this answer.
- Another factor in  making the answer long is that it is an attempt to show how I might think about this problem.